# Devise with Rails Not Creating Users Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm a Rails beginner, and I am trying to make a site with a signup page that creates users in a database I set up. I installed devise (seemingly) correctly, and after creating the first user to test it out, everything seemed to work. However, if I try creating another user, it doesn't work. After clicking create user on the page, it goes back to the homepage without any errors or anything. But when I check the users table in my database, I can see the user was not created.

I got it to work when I changed the first users id (primary key) from 2 to 1. And the new user's id was 3. So it looks like for whatever reason, devise wants to skip a step, or is somehow trying to insert twice or something. But once again, even after I got the new user to create, if I try again it doesn't work.

Here's a printout of the rails server during the create request:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-05-26 16:08:26 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zl39rAOLLSRoEZUIcX574BlJtNgySlz/d5FRNIg3ZjuvcdQJxOVLDdWPAp3jQqhT3g1H0PCexFdHdmAQD81CKQ==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"asdasd", "last_name"=>"asdasd", "email"=>"asdasd@asda.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "instructor"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create my account"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Here is my UsersController file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.active = 1
  end

   def create
     @user = User.new(sign_up_params)    # Not the final implementation!
     if @user.save
       redirect_to :action => :index
     else
       render 'signup'
     end
   end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

 private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :instructor, :active)
   end

end
```

And here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>New User</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email %>

      <%= check_box_tag(:instructor) %>
        <center><%= label_tag(:instructor, "I want to be an instructor") %></center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :confirm_password %>
      <%= f.password_field :confirm_password %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide

Comment: Are you logged in when you submit?  The devise method `require_no_authentication` will redirect you if you are.

Comment: The whole point of Devise is that it provides a ready made solution for authentication with views, controllers etc. If you want to learn how to make an authentication system as a beginner don't start by hacking Devise. The code is pretty complex since it needs to have a crazy level of flexibility. Instead check out something like https://www.railstutorial.org

Comment: Does Devise automatically log you in after you create a user?

Answer (score 1):

Devise will not allow you to create new users while logged in as a user yourself.  If you need this functionality (adding users through your web application while logged into it) and don't want to add Users from the rails console you will have to work around Devise a little bit like follows:

Create a Users controller: `rails g controller Users`
Then in your routes you will have to specify:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
  resources :users_crew, :controller => 'users'
```

Then in your new UsersController you can do what you want such as:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :admin?, except: [:index]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success]="User added"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error]="Something went wrong, please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index

  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success]="User and oversight updated"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error]="Something went wrong, please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "The user account has been deleted."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Sorry, user record was not changed."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :password, :password_confirmation) 
  end

end
```

This basically tells Devise we only need it for sessions.  The users_crew resource points to the User controller so we can add our custom logic there and not worry about hacking up Devise in the process.  Make sure you feed a password and password_confirmation attributes to your User.create method since Devise will still handle registrations etc.

Lastly, remember that your routes for Users will now be like '`users_crew_path`' etc. if you used my routes above.  Type `bundle exec rake routes` to get a full list of all the routes you have setup as well as their helpers if you aren't sure.